# DataSet/DataGridView setting selected columns to a variable .VB

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

Is it possible to set a selected Data Grid View column name to a variable.

Example of my code.

```
    Dim cmevoids As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
    Dim test As String
    test = "event_code"

    Dim Query = From payments In cmevoids.AsEnumerable() _
                Where payments.Field(Of String)("event_code") = "MB120117"
                Where payments.Field(Of String)("event_transaction_status") = "PAID"
    Order By payments.Field(Of String)("event_code") _
                Select New With {.event_code = payments.Field(Of String)(test), _
                                        .event_transaction_status = payments.Field(Of String)("event_transaction_status"), _
                                        .event_transaction_detail_amount = payments.Field(Of String)("event_transaction_detail_amount")}
    dgvQuery.DataSource = Query.ToList()
```

I want to take w/e column the user selects from a combo box from the first data grid view and display it in a 2nd data grid view for query's.

I can get it to search and display the table selected by the variable given as shown by the test variable. But i can't get it to change the column name in the query data grid view to the name of the variable. I can only get it to name it w/e i have hard coded in, in this case event_code, event_transaction_status and event_transaction_detail_amount.

Any way to do this without hard code but variable?

Answer (score 0):

What about populating the gridview like you have been but then change it after it is bound?

```
Dim Result as string = "w/e column the user selects from a combo box"
Dim i as integer = 0 'your colum index
GridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText = Result
```